# Python3 Flask route variable shows up as the variable name instead of value passed from postman

Tags: python, routes, url-routing, flask-restful, url-parameters

I have the following python flask api route:

```
@user_api.route("/<int:id>", methods=["GET"])
@Authentication.auth_required
def get_user(id):
    """
    Get a user
    """
    print(f"User id: {id}")
    user = user_schema.dump(UserModel.get_user(id))
    if not user:
        print(f"User id: {id} not found!")
        return custom_response({"error": f"User {id} not found!"}, 400)
    return custom_response(user_schema.dump(user), 200)
```

`GET` from postman at `http://localhost:5555/api/v1/users/5` always ends up with:

```
{
    "error": "User id not found!"
}
```

And the python console output shows:

```
User id: id
User id: id not found!
```

which means that the route variable ends up in the function as variable name but not value. This happens for both `int` and `string` variable types. This is bizarre. What do I miss?

Comment: what you get if you print `repr(id)` before you do anything else?

Comment: User id: id, 'id'

Comment: Have you tried change the named parameter to `xpto` to see what happens? Proof tested the code you share, it prints corrects values to integers in path.

Comment: Could it be that `id` is a variable name used by your decorator? And is thus overwritten before reaching `get_user`? So what happens if you change the name temporarily.

Comment: I tried `userid` and same result. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to mistake in the `@Authentication.auth_required` decorator function when passing the `kwargs` to the decorated function. It missed one asterisk. So instead of `**kwargs` it mistakenly passed `*kwargs`.